# iOS 5 Core Graphics Memory Spike

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I recently tuned my app to be more memory efficient and ran into a weird memory problem on iOS5. Note my app does not have automatic reference counting turned on. First, I got the live memory from 15Mb down to 10Mb and it works great on any iOS6 device and the iOS6 simulator. When I ran the tuned app on iOS5 (iPad or simulator), it hits a point at startup where it spikes >100Mb within a second and usually gets terminated. The memory that's spiking is happening purely in iOS code.

I've attached two instruments screen shots - the first showing the spike, and the second showing a malloc call which causes it - note the stack trace on the right. All those large malloc calls are in the same point of the code.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this. I've read several posts about leaks in Core Graphics and the stack trace shows that. My best guess about what's happening is that somehow the change to make the app more memory efficient triggered something in Core Graphics that makes it want to use (and leak) more memory, but only in iOS5.

Any ideas or insights as to what might be the cause and how to fix it would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you haven't posted any relevant code, a wild guess: are you sure you got the reference counting right?

Comment: Change the view to "Call Tree" in instruments and tick the boxes "Hide Missing Symbols", "Hide System Libraries" and "Show Obj-C only". Then alt-click-drag the memory spike. This will show you all the functions running during the memory spike.

Comment: Also, try the static analyser in Xcode. It's good at spotting un released memory that has been statically allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. A couple of follow-ups: H2CO3, I know it's not a problem with my reference counting because it doesn't happen on iOS6 and the leak is happening entirely within system code. Fogmeister, I've been using static analysis regularly (I love that tool) and it isn't seeing any problems. I tried your suggestion of using the call tree (I didn't know you could alt-drag, thanks), but it verified what the screen shot shows for the mallocs - that all of the code is happening outside of mine.